# pandas add missing rows from list

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset which looks like this:

```
data = [
 {'frame_id': 111, 'circle': 3, 'square': 5, 'triangle': 7},
 {'frame_id': 222, 'circle': 1, 'square': 10, 'triangle': 0}
]
```

I have a list of frame_ids:

```
frame_ids = [111, 222, 333, 444]
```

I would like to fill in records for the missing frame_id, with 0 values

results should be:

```
res = [
 {'frame_id': 111, 'circle': 3, 'square': 5, 'triangle': 7},
 {'frame_id': 222, 'circle': 1, 'square': 10, 'triangle': 0},
 {'frame_id': 333, 'circle': 0, 'square': 0, 'triangle': 0},
 {'frame_id': 444, 'circle': 0, 'square': 0, 'triangle': 0}
]
```

here I am loading my data frame:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

how can I continue to achieve the result using pandas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) and [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df1 = df.set_index('frame_id').reindex(frame_ids, fill_value=0).reset_index()
print (df1)
   frame_id  circle  square  triangle
0       111       3       5         7
1       222       1      10         0
2       333       0       0         0
3       444       0       0         0

print (df1.to_dict('records'))
[{'frame_id': 111, 'circle': 3, 'square': 5, 'triangle': 7}, 
 {'frame_id': 222, 'circle': 1, 'square': 10, 'triangle': 0},
 {'frame_id': 333, 'circle': 0, 'square': 0, 'triangle': 0}, 
 {'frame_id': 444, 'circle': 0, 'square': 0, 'triangle': 0}]
```